# avgrund plugin not blurring or introducing background

Tags: jquery, css, avgrund

I'm trying to get the avgrund plugin working on my site and I've had *some* success, but the blur and background effects are not working properly.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC2jf.jpg)

I've got an exact duplicate of the css file used [here](http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/) and it is importing properly.

I've tried removing the class '.avgrund-blur' from this css:

```
.avgrund-active .avgrund-blur {
-webkit-filter: blur(1px);
-moz-filter: blur(1px);
-ms-filter: blur(1px);
-o-filter: blur(1px);
filter: blur(1px); 
}
```

that succeeded in making the page blur, but it also blurred the popup window.

I haven't even tried to figure out why the background is white on my site rather than the black pattern that appears behind the sample, but eventually that's going to need to be straightened out as well.  Anyone have any idea what is causing these problems?

EDIT: I've resolved the background issue.  Turns out that was simply a matter of setting the html{} background property.  The blur issue remains a problem however.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own issue.  In case anyone else runs into this problem in the future, the solution was to specify the blur container within the avgrund function.  Like so:

```
$('.con-body-questionmark-link').avgrund({
    onBlurContainer: '#id',
});
```